# Is Express Trader Profits real or a scam?

Tags: scams, online-trading

Someone texted me in IG who introduce himself as a crypto trade expert and convinced me to invest in thier company Express Trader Profits. This company offers trading services in your behalf and you will be recieving a profit from your investment without doing nothing. I invested 126USD. So far so good. Now my profit is more than 9K USD. When I make a withdrawal the system bot ask me for the COT code.I recieved an emai.from.them saying that I need to fee 601USD for security and maintenance fee. My account will be in pending mode until made the payment. Is the COT code that I was asked to provide is related to this? Please advice. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, but you got scammed. Your $126 are gone, and any further money you pay in relation to this scheme will be gone too.

Comment: Note that there **is no 9K profit**. The scammers will have created a website to make it _look_ like you've made a profit.

Comment: Any offer of guaranteed safe high returns will only end up costing you money.

Comment: If I can turn $100 into $9000 then I don't need your $100 to make my money.

Comment: In general, never trust anyone who randomly contacts you on social media about money. It's going to be a scam 100% of the time.